# Tableview - WHITE screen only - Outlet still connected but no rows are shown

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiview, cell, rows

Im in trouble with my UIViewController. At this view in storyboard the simulator shows the datepicker, save-button and a edit button. But my tableview seems to be hidden. There is a white screen only. Than I styled the table with a background and than my "empty rows" where shown in simulator, but there is no scroling etc... So, I see the table but now rows I think... What is the problem?

Here are my outlets in .h file:
The *tableview is stll connected.

```
    @interface NotifierViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;
    IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
    IBOutlet UITextField *eventText;
    NSMutableArray *notificationsArray;
    UILocalNotification *notifcation;
    UISegmentedControl *scheduleControl;

}
```

And the Cell in my.m file:

```
    // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...


    self.notificationsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]];
    notifcation = [self.notificationsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //UILocalNotification *notif = [notificationsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //NSArray *notificationArray = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
    //UILocalNotification *notif = [notificationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Was in der Zelle als Titel steht
    //[[cell textLabel] setText:[notifcation alertBody]];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:@"alarm"];
    //[cell.detailTextLabel setText:[notif.fireDate description]];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:notifcation.fireDate]];
    [dateFormatter release];
    return cell;
}
```

In the inspector I named the Identifier "Cell", too
Style is Basic and I decided for Dynamic Prototypes in the Content section with 1 Cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My default was ...

I have to connect the delegate and dataSource to MyViewController.

**Inspector View:**

Outlets:

- delegate   -> MyViewController
- dataSource -> MyViewController

Referencing Outlets:

- mytableView -> MyViewController